# How many Spring Boot application on one machine

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot for my product development.
I have created 15+ small spring boot projects each as independent microservice.

I have deployed on AWS cloud with 8 GB RAM machine.My long term goal is to distribute all microservice on separate machines but that is still a month or two away.

I am still in Beta Testing and want to know, is it good to have 15+ service on one machine(I will go production live in a week). For now they seem to be OK during my test after I set PermSize.

Can you please share your experience, any practices or thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be a problem IMHO. Usually you should worry about the workload of services, not how many (potentially idle) services you have. And microservices offer good horizontal scalability so if you need you can easily expand with these.